# Django : Why is string condition False if select_related field not coated in STR()?

Tags: django, string, if-statement, django-select-related

In my function, my query is :

```
 mappings = MappingField.objects.filter(
        fl_fiche_header_flow_id=fhf.pk).order_by('fl_fiche_inside_field_position')
            .select_related('fl_fiche_header_flow')
```

Why when I print (label is models.Charfield):

```
mapping.fl_fiche_header_flow.label
```

I got well :  `appli1`

And when I check the condition :

```
if mapping.fl_fiche_header_flow.label == 'appli1':
```

I obtain `False`?

Why do I need to `str(mapping.fl_fiche_header_flow.label)` in my condition for getting `true`?

Is it only due to `select_related` or is it a general principle ?

Comment: Because `.label` is not a string, but likely a `Label` object or something similar...

Comment: It seems to be a string. Because when I `print(mapping.fl_fiche_header_flow.label)`, the result is 'appli1' . That's the reason of my question.

Comment: And what do you get if you do `print(type(mapping.fl_fiche_header_flow.label))`?

Comment: @Abpostman1: if you `print(..)` it calls `str(..)` on the item, and prints that content...

Comment: @Abpostman1: there is a difference between an object that `str(..)`s to `'x'` and the string `'x'`.

Comment: @solarissmoke:  Exact: it's an object type : `<class 'flows.models.FicheHeader'>`.  @Willem Van Onsem : thanks for the tip. I didn't know this. Thanks